# Gravar labels num ficheiro e fazer load da informação

Tags: c#, .net, lista, label

Eu estou a tentar criar uma maneira para:

1. criar várias labels por um botão - feito;
2. gravar a informação dessas labels numa lista (texto, left coords e top coords) - feito como apresento a seguir;
3. fazer load dessa lista pela ordem de texto, left, top para recriar a label no mesmo local depois de ter desligado a app - dificuldade neste passo;

O código que tenho para já é o seguinte:

```
List <String> labelList = new List<String>(); //lista para texto
List<int> labelLeft = new List<int>(); //coords left
List<int> labelTop = new List<int>(); //coords top
```

O que eu tenho para o botão de escrita no ficheiro é o seguinte:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Label label1 in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
    {
        labelList.Add(label1.Text); //id da label é "label1"
        labelLeft.Add(label1.Left);
        labelTop.Add(label1.Top);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < labelList.Count(); i++)
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedGame.txt");

        // write lines of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(labelList[i].Text);
        tw.WriteLine(labelLeft[i]);
        tw.WriteLine(labelTop[i]);

        // close the stream     
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Que para já não tenho problema, a ideia é escrever os dados no ficheiro cada vez que o ciclo roda uma vez assim que tenho os dados todos na primeira lista.

Agora a minha dificuldade está em ler os dados para os voltar a reproduzir pois o que eu tentei foi o seguinte:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < labelList.Count(); i++)
    {
        Label l = new Label();
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("SavedGame.txt");

        string ltext = tr.ReadLine();
        string labelLeft = tr.ReadLine();
        string labelTop = tr.ReadLine();

        //Convert the strings to int
        l.Text = ltext;
        l.Left = Convert.ToInt32(labelLeft);
        l.Top = Convert.ToInt32(labelTop);

        // close the stream
        tr.Close();
    }
}
```

Eu sei que o meu script de leitura pode estar errado mas ha alguma maneira de eu alcançar o pretendido que expliquei acima?

Obrigado.

Comment: Qual erro ocorreu? Teve qual dificuldade exatamente?

Comment: a dificuldade está em recriar a label que foi guardada atraves dos dados que sao guardados no ficheiro. Neste momento o ficheiro está a guardar o texto e os dados relativos a posiçao. Nao estou a conseguir, depois de fechar o programa, usar o que está no ficheiro para colocar a label no ecra outra vez na mesma posiçao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma simulação e encontrei dois problemas:

1. Ao salvar, você está sobreescrevendo o txt.
   use `TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("SavedGame.txt", true);` para dar append ao invés de sobreescrever o arquivo.
2. Você está gerando o label mas não está adicionando ele ao `form`.
   Use `this.Controls.Add(l);` para adicionar o `Label` `l` no `form`.